# Casting integers to a char value

Tags: java

Hi guys is there a way to convert `int`s to their respective ASCII values?

I tried simply casting an `int` to `char` but I don't think its possible. Is there a way to get around that?

Comment: Why do you think it's not possible? What is the ASCII value of `123456789`?

Comment: I don't really understand your question here. If you're trying to convert an `int` to its respective ASCII value, don't you already know the value of it?